# Spring MVC 6.1.0 cannot automatically accept query string parameters while 6.0.6 can

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Body:**

I am encountering an issue with Spring MVC version 6.1.0 where it seems unable to automatically receive query string parameters, whereas version 6.0.6 can handle this automatically.

Below is the controller code I'm using:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/param")
public class ParamController {

    @GetMapping("/simple")
    @ResponseBody
    String simpleData(String name,int age){
        System.out.println("name = " + name + ", age = " + age);
        return name+age;
    }
}
```

Spring Framework 相关依赖：

- org.springframework:spring-webmvc: 6.0.6: Spring MVC 框架，用于构建基于 Spring 的 Web 应用程序。
  org.springframework:spring-test: 6.0.6: Spring 测试框架，用于编写和执行 Spring 应用程序的单元测试和集成测试。
  Lombok 依赖：
- org.projectlombok:lombok: 1.18.30: Lombok 是一个 Java 库，通过注解消除了 Java 的样板代码，并提供了一些便利功能，以提高开发效率。
  Servlet API 依赖：
- jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api: 9.1.0: Jakarta EE Web API，提供了 Jakarta EE Web 相关的 API，包括 Servlet API，用于开发 Web 应用程序。

Comment: Add `@RequestParam` as you should have. Also make sure you are compiling with the `-parameters` flag as that is now required as the fallback has been removed

Answer (score 0):

fix your code like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/param")
public class ParamController {
   @GetMapping("/simple")
   String simpleData(@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam int age){
      System.out.println("name = " + name + ", age = " + age);
      return name+age;
   }
}
```

Comment: 可是6.0.6及以前不需要显式添加@RequestParam就可以使用，是否意味着以后版本都必须加了。官方是否有说明呢

Comment: 没有关注过官方说明
spring mvc参数隐式行为过于复杂、需要逐个尝试确认、最好的情况是显示指定